# PyQt5 - Custom QWidget not showing up on parent widget

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, pyqt, widget, pyqt5

I am working on a game in which I have completed the engine and the networking layers. I am now working on some GUI for the game using PyQt5 (as the drawing isn't complex). I made a custom QWidget for drawing the game board which is just a widget that positions custom QPushButtons inside itself. Here's the code for that:

```
class BoardButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    tilePressed = pyqtSignal(Tile)

    def __init__(self, tile: Tile = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setCheckable(False)
        self.setDefault(False)
        self.setFlat(False)
        self.raise_()
        self.tile = tile
        self.default_background(tile)
        self.highlight = False
        self.is_clicked = False

    def __change_bgd(self, colour):
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), colour)
        self.setPalette(p)

    def default_background(self, tile: Tile):
        if tile == self.tile:
            self.__change_bgd(QtGui.QColor(153, 76, 0))

    def highlight_background(self, tile: Tile):
        if tile == self.tile:
            self.__change_bgd(QtCore.Qt.green)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e: QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        self.tilePressed.emit(self.tile)

    def paintEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QPaintEvent) -> None:
        if self.highlight:
            self.highlight_background(self.tile)
        else:
            self.default_background(self.tile)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        if self.tile:
            if self.tile.is_special:
                first_line = self.width() / 3
                second_line = first_line * 2
                painter.drawLine(first_line, 0, first_line, self.height())
                painter.drawLine(second_line, 0, second_line, self.height())
                painter.drawLine(0, first_line, self.width(), first_line)
                painter.drawLine(0, second_line, self.width(), second_line)
            if self.tile.is_exit:
                painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
                painter.drawEllipse(self.width() / 4, self.height() / 4, self.width() / 2, self.height() / 2)
            if self.tile.piece is not None:
                if self.tile.piece.is_white:
                    colour = QtCore.Qt.white
                else:
                    colour = QtCore.Qt.black
                painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(colour, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
                painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
                if self.tile.piece.is_king:
                    painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white, QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern))
                    painter.drawEllipse(self.width() / 4, self.height() / 4, self.width() / 2, self.height() / 2)


class GameBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    tilePressed = pyqtSignal(Tile)
    boardUpdate = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, game: Game = None, is_white: bool = None, playable=True, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 650, 650))
        self.setObjectName("boardWidget")
        self.game = game
        self.is_white = is_white
        self.playable = playable
        self.buttons = []
        self.__selected = None
        self.tilePressed.connect(self.__tile_pressed)

    def init_buttons(self):
        def pos_to_name(x, y):
            return f'btn_{x}{y}'

        self.buttons = []
        board = self.game.board
        board_size = board.width
        if board.width > board.height:
            board_size = board.width
        elif board.width < board.height:
            board_size = board.height
        btn_size = self.width() / board_size
        start_x = self.width() / 2 - btn_size * (board.width / 2)
        start_y = self.height() / 2 - btn_size * (board.height / 2)

        for y in range(board.height):
            row = []
            for x in range(board.width):
                button = BoardButton(board[y][x], parent=self)
                button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(start_x + x * btn_size, start_y + y * btn_size, btn_size, btn_size))
                button.setObjectName(pos_to_name(x, y))
                button.tilePressed.connect(self.tilePressed.emit)
                row.append(button)
            self.buttons.append(row)

    def __get_button(self, tile: Tile) -> BoardButton:
        return self.buttons[tile.y][tile.x]

    def update(self) -> None:
        self.boardUpdate.emit()
        for y, row in enumerate(self.buttons):
            for x, button in enumerate(row):
                button.tile = self.game.board[y][x]
                button.update()
        super().update()

    def remove_highlights(self):
        self.__selected = None
        for row in self.buttons:
            for button in row:
                button.highlight = False
                button.is_clicked = False

    def highlight_buttons(self, source_tile: Tile):
        self.__selected = source_tile
        for tile in self.game.board.valid_moves(source_tile):
            self.buttons[tile.y][tile.x].highlight = True

    def move_piece(self, target_tile: Tile):
        if not self.__selected:
            raise ValueError('Cannot move piece because no piece is selected.')

        self.game.move(self.__selected, target_tile)

    def is_highlight(self, tile: Tile) -> bool:
        return self.__get_button(tile).highlight

    def is_clicked(self, tile: Tile) -> bool:
        return self.__get_button(tile).is_clicked

    def set_clicked(self, tile: Tile, value: bool):
        self.__get_button(tile).is_clicked = value

    def __tile_pressed(self, tile: Tile):
        if not tile or self.game.game_over or not self.playable:
            return

        if self.is_white is not None and not is_turn(self.is_white, self.game):
            return

        if not tile.piece and self.is_highlight(tile):
            try:
                self.move_piece(tile)
            except (BoardGameException, Win):
                pass
            self.remove_highlights()

        elif not tile.piece and not self.is_highlight(tile):
            self.remove_highlights()

        elif tile.piece:
            if self.is_clicked(tile):
                self.remove_highlights()
            elif self.game.is_turn(tile):
                self.remove_highlights()
                self.highlight_buttons(tile)
                self.set_clicked(tile, True)

        self.update()
```

This code works perfectly with one of my windows:

```
class LocalGameWindow(Ui_FrmLocalGame):
    def __init__(self, game, playable=True):
        super().__init__(game=game, playable=playable)
        self.init_gameboard()
        self.gameboard.update()
        if self.gameboard.playable:
            self.btnUndo.clicked.connect(self.btn_undo_clicked)
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle(...)
            self.btnUndo.setText('Play')
            self.lblTurn.setVisible(False)
            self.lblBlackPieces.setVisible(False)
            self.lblWhitePieces.setVisible(False)
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def btn_undo_clicked(self):
        self.gameboard.game.undo()
        self.gameboard.update()
```

Which inherits from the following (Ui_FrmLocalGame was generated with Qt Designer):

```
class Ui_FrmLocalGame(_GameBoardWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, FrmLocalGame):
        ...
```

Which in turn inherits from:

```
class _GameBoardWindow(GameWidget):
    def __init__(self, client: Client = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        is_white = None
        if client:
            is_white = client.is_white
        self.gameboard = GameBoard(is_white=is_white, *args, **kwargs, parent=self)
        self.client = client
        self.gameboard.boardUpdate.connect(self.update_labels)

    def init_gameboard(self, game: Game = None):
        if game:
            self.gameboard.game = game
        self.gameboard.init_buttons()

    def update_labels(self):
        game = self.gameboard.game
        if not game:
            return

        if not game.game_over:
            text = f"{'Black' if game.black.is_turn else 'White'}'s Turn"
        else:
            text = f"{'Black' if game.black.won else 'White'} Won!"
        self.lblTurn.setText(text)
        self.lblBlackPieces.setText(f'Black: {game.board.num_black}/{game.board.num_start_black}')
        self.lblWhitePieces.setText(f'White: {game.board.num_white}/{game.board.num_start_white}')
```

This gives me the result I expect, it draws the gameboard widget on the window widget:
[image]

However, when I try to do seemingly the same thing with a different window widget (the online window), it just doesn't appear on the window as it does with the local game window. Here's the code for the window:

```
class Ui_FrmOnlineGame(_GameBoardWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, FrmOnlineGame):
        ...

class OnlineGameWindow(Ui_FrmOnlineGame):
    def __init__(self, client: Client):
        super().__init__(client=client)
        self.btnSend.clicked.connect(self.btn_send_clicked)
        self.txtChat.returnPressed.connect(self.btn_send_clicked)
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.__timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.__timer.setInterval(100)
        self.__timer.timeout.connect(self.__game_loop)
        self.__timer.start()

    def __game_loop(self):
        try:
            msg = self.client.recv_msg()
        except BlockingIOError:
            return

        ...

        elif msg.startswith(Message.GameUpdate.value):
            game = Game.from_serial(msg[1:])
            self.gameboard.game = game
            if not len(self.gameboard.buttons):
                self.init_gameboard()
            self.gameboard.update()  # This should draw the gameboard widget like it does on the other window

        ...

    def display_chat(self, text: str):
        ...

    def display_colour(self):
        show_dialog(f"You are {'white' if self.client.is_white else 'black'}.", self, 'Game Start', modal=False)

    def btn_send_clicked(self):
        ...

    def close(self) -> bool:
        self.__timer.stop()
        self.client.exit()
        return super().close()
```

I've tried many things such as checking the custom widget's geometry, raising it, and making sure that it does have a parent (which it does). What have I done wrong? Any help would be appreciated, and sorry about all the code, I just feel it's necessary to find the issue.

Comment: please provide a   [mre]

Comment: The problem is that I've tried reproducing it with a simple window but it worked fine, it's just that one window that it does not work with